# Path environment variable deleted and Visual Studio not working

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, environment-variables

Good morning,

I deleted the "path" environment variable and now I´m not able to open Visual Studio. I tried most of the solutions that have been commented in other threads, but most of them are based on a sistem recovery, which I didn´t have configured.

Most of the programms keep working, but I have problems with Visual Studio. I tried to reinstall it, but it still doesn´t work. I would like to know which are the "path"-s that Visual Studio needs to work in order to recover it.

I use Windows 10.

Comment: I also tried to add the Windows 10 default paths to the "path" variable, but nothing happened

Comment: Try running `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` - you should be able to launch `devenv` from there. FYI this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.